# Write $(12)(13)(14)$ in the form $\alpha(12)$. Write $(1234) (12)(23)$ in the form $\alpha(1234)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am learning normal subgroups and factor subgroups. I am using the textbook *Contemporary Abstract Algebra*, 8th edition, by Joseph A. Gallian, and I stumbled upon an exercise question (Exercise 4, Chapter 9), which reads:

> Write $(12)(13)(14)$ in the form $\alpha(12)$, where $\alpha\in A_4$. Write $(1234)(12)(23)$ in the form $\alpha(1234)$, where $\alpha\in A_4$.

I know how to set up the equations:

- $(12)(13)(14) = \alpha(12)$
- $(1234)(12)(23) = \alpha(1234)$

but I'm a bit stuck on what should I do next. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hint for the first one: multiply both sides of the equation on the right by $(1\ 2)^{-1} = (1\ 2)$. Similarly for the second one.

Comment: Ahh, I see. So when I multiply the first equation, I get (12)(13)(14)(12) = (243). I believe that's the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(12)(13)(14) = \alpha(12)$ then multiply both sides by $(12)$ on the right, and $(12)(12) = e$, the identity, so

$\alpha = (12)(13)(14)(12) \in A_4$ (it has an even number of transpositions so it's in $A_4$, but the standard form is $(243)$ of course.

For the second we start from $$(1234)(12)(23) = \alpha(1234)$$ and multiply on the right by $(4321)$, the inverse of $(1234)$ and we get

$$\alpha = (1234)(12)(23)(4321) = (234) \in A_4$$

Comment: Wow, thanks for the help! Highly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

For any cycle $\sigma=(s_1\dots s_m)\in S_n$ and any $\tau\in S_n$, we have $$\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}=(\tau(s_1)\dots \tau(s_m)),$$ where $\tau(s_i)$ is $\tau$ evaluated at $s_i$.